# Jenkins executing maven from incorrect path

Tags: maven, jenkins

This happens for both: maven projects, and freestyle projects, when maven target is envoked, it tries to execute mvn using absolute path.

```
[MY-Job] $ tools/Maven/Jenkins_Private_Maven/bin/mvn -f cc/pom.xml -Ddeploy_env=xxx.dev.prv   -Dbranch=dev -D-Dsmdist.target=/opt/builds -U clean test -DtestGroups=unit,delegate -Do verride:server=xxx.dev.prv
FATAL: command execution failed 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tools/Maven/Jenkins_Private_Maven/bin/mvn" (in    directory "workspace/MY-Job"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I can see that mvn is installed at user's home :

```
/home/jenkins/tools/Maven/Jenkins_Private_Maven/bin/mvn
```

but it's trying to run it from the workspace:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/MY-Job/tools/Maven/Jenkins_Private_Maven/bin/mvn
```

Answer (score 24):

1. Add the default maven installation under (Jenkins -> configuration)
   [image: Jenkins -> configuration -> Maven]
2. Goto the failing job and make sure you choose the default maven installation from dropdown 
   [image: Config in failing Job]
3. Run the job. Success!

Comment: In new Jenkins version 2.x it's under Global Tool Configuration under Manage Jenkins and 2nd step is not required.  I'm not sure with newer version is it necessary at all ?

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure you have set up Maven  in **Jenkins -> configuration** like this

[image]

I have hunch you have a accidental `**"."**` current directory reference somewhere in your maven set up.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an auto installed Maven by Jenkins.  In which case the previous answers are not correct.

It would seem in this occasion that you have not specified a "remote fs root" for your slave in the salve setup - later versions of Jenkins flag not setting this up correctly as an error.

[image: slave config screen]

Answer (score 0):

in Jenkins 2.43:

Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Maven

[image]

Comment: if maven have installed, then uncheck 'Install automatically' and specify maven name and path. Finally specify maven name in job config instead default