# Hudson Maven SVN Release Error

Tags: maven, svn, hudson, hudson-plugins

Getting `Can't run goal clean compile` error when I do Maven Release through Hudson. Can someone please help.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can't run goal clean compile

java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can't run goal clean compile
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:583)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:482)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:165)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:159)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:688)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:632)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can't run goal clean compile
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:451)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Can't run goal clean compile
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:66)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:136)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Can't run goal clean compile
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.ForkedMavenExecutor.executeGoals(ForkedMavenExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.ForkedMavenExecutor.executeGoals(ForkedMavenExecutor.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:59)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while executing process.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute(Commandline.java:697)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.ForkedMavenExecutor.executeCommandLine(ForkedMavenExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.ForkedMavenExecutor.executeGoals(ForkedMavenExecutor.java:104)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "<http://localhost:8090/job/bbc/ws/trunk")>: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute(Commandline.java:692)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: That looks like the cause of the problem: ` Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "<http://localhost:8090/job/bbc/ws/trunk")>: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`. Can you show the configuration part of Hudson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [thread elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822913/jenkins-executing-maven-from-incorrect-path) might help.

Jenkins looks for the `mvn` binary under `$M2_HOME/bin/`.

The `ws/trunk` in your logs suggests `M2_HOME` is pointing to `$WORKSPACE`:

```
(in directory "<http://localhost:8090/job/bbc/ws/trunk")
```

But usually `$WORKSPACE` is a file path, not a url.

All of which is to say, double check both your `M2_HOME` and `WORKSPACE` env variables.

The `M2_HOME` in particular is confusing since Jenkins lets you defined it at both instance and job level.