# Jenkins:can not see test report tab

Tags: jenkins, junit

I can not see report tab here:

[image: no tab]

Public Junit test report:

[image: Public Junit test report]

I have configured Public JUnit test report, but I still can not see test report in left area.

Comment: Make sure you have some .xml files in **/target/sunfire-reports/*.xml

Comment: yes, there are some xml files in  surefire-reports folder.

Answer (score 0):

As the [OP joan.li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7561702/joan-li) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816025/jenkinscan-not-see-test-report-tab/44816425#comment76656064_44816425), you need to make sure Your Jenkins installation knows about maven (as mentioned in "[Jenkins executing maven from incorrect path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13822913/6309)"):

> 1. Add the default maven installation under (Jenkins -> configuration)
>    [image: Jenkins -> configuration -> Maven]
> 2. Goto the failing job and make sure you choose the default maven installation from dropdown
>    [image: Config in failing Job]

And You need to make sure your [`pom.xml` does include a surefire build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527702/jenkins-not-finding-surefire-reports)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25650361/6309).

Check if those xml files are generated

Comment: <plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
<formats>
<format>xml</format>
<format>html</format>
</formats>
</configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: @joan.li Don't hesitate to edit your question to add new information.

Comment: there are some xml files in surefire-reports folder.

Comment: @joan.li you still need to check that your build step in your maven build does include a surefire step, as configured in my answer.

Comment: So that would be what is missing in your case. Check the first link in my answer for a complete pom.xml example.

Comment: I have solved the problem,Just Scroll down about half way to the Maven section and click Maven installations. Give your path to your Maven install in MAVEN_HOME.

Comment: @joan.li Right! I have added the relevant step and illustrations to the answer for more visibility.